# What is the derivative of the given function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

This is the question: What is the derivative of this function?
     $$\frac{2^{x}}{e^{x}}$$

I have seen two answers for this question and I would like to know which one is correct and which one is not.

This is one:

$$\frac{d}{dx} \left( \left( \frac{2}{e} \right)^x \right) = \left( \frac{2}{e} \right)^x \log \left( \frac{2}{e} \right)$$

since the derivative of $(2/e)^x$ is $$\left( \frac{2}{e} \right)^x \log \left( \frac{2}{e} \right).$$

And the other one is where you re-write the function to be $2^{x}e^{-x}$ and use the product rule. Which one is it, I'm confused on how to approach this question.

Comment: Both should arrive at the same answer, without worrying about the form that it is in...

Comment: So the first one is correct?

Comment: Yes, as long as "log" is the natural logarithm.

Comment: but the natural logarithm is ,e.

Comment: The derivative of a function is unique.  The technique that you use to arrive at such a derivative may put the answer in a different form than another technique, but they should be equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

They're both correct.
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\left(\frac{2}{e}\right)^x\right) &= \left(\frac{2}{e}\right)^x\log\frac{2}{e}\\
&= \left(\frac{2}{e}\right)^x(\log 2 - \log e)\\
&= \left(\frac{2}{e}\right)^x\log 2 - \left(\frac{2}{e}\right)^x\\
&= 2^x e^{-x}\log 2 - 2^x e^{-x}\\
&= \color{red}{2^x\log 2}\cdot e^{-x} + 2^x\color{blue}{(-e^{-x})}\\
&= e^{-x}\color{red}{\frac{d}{dx}\left(2^x\right)} + 2^x\color{blue}{\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{-x}\right)}\\
&= \frac{d}{dx}\left(2^x\cdot e^{-x}\right)
\end{align*}

Comment: $+1=+1$, yup everything checks out.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac {d\left(\frac 2e\right)^x}{dx}=\left(\frac 2e\right)^x\ln \frac 2e=\left(\frac 2e\right)^x(\ln 2-1)$$

$$\frac {d\frac {2^x}{e^x}}{dx}=\frac {2^xe^x\ln 2-2^xe^x}{(e^x)^2}=\frac {2^x}{e^x}(\ln 2-1)$$

$$\frac {d(2^xe^{-x})}{dx}=2^xe^{-x}\ln 2+2^xe^{-x}(-1)=\frac {2^x}{e^x}(\ln 2-1)$$

It should be apparent that these are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Write $2^x = e^{x \ln(2)}$.
The function becomes $$ e^{(-1+\ln(2))x}$$
The derivative is 
$$ (-1+\ln(2))e^{(-1+\ln(2))x}$$
You can simplify it by writing it as
$$ (-1+\ln(2)) \left(e^{-x} e^{x \ln(2)}\right) = (\ln(2)-1) \left(e^{-x} 2^x\right) =(\ln(2)-1) \left(\frac{2}{e}\right)^x = \ln\left(\frac{2}{e}\right)\left(\frac{2}{e}\right)^x $$

Comment: Minor pedantic comment: $$\ln\left(\frac 2e\right)\left(\frac 2e\right)^x$$ is not necessarily clear as being the same as $$\left(\frac 2e\right)^x\ln\left(\frac 2e\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\left(\frac2e\right)^x\right)=\frac d{dx}\left(e^{x\log\frac2e}\right)=\log\frac2ee^{x\log\frac 2e}=\left(\frac2e\right)^x\log\frac2e$$